# How to get the local json file path in angular2 nativescript

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-services

- I'm new to nativescript angular2. So far I followed documentation and
  did static datas with listview.
- I placed my json file in `app/utils/countries.json`.
- I don't know how to get the local file path to parse the json.Need suggestion regarding this.
- Below I have posted the codes for listview with static data.

**typescript:**

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "ns-app",
    templateUrl: "app.component.html",
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

 arrList: Array<Object> = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.arrList.push({ name: "India" });
    this.arrList.push({ name: "Sri Lanka" });
  }

 }
```

**HTML:**

```
<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>

<GridLayout>
  <ListView [items]="arrList" class="small-spacing">
    <ng-template let-item="item">
      <Label [text]="item.name" class="medium-spacing"></Label>
    </ng-template>
  </ListView>
</GridLayout>
```

**countries.json:** (app/utils/countries.json):

```
{
  "countries": [
              {"id":1,"name":"india"},
              {"id":2,"name":"Sri Lanka"}

   ]
}
```

Comment: youre wanting to import a json file that you have within your `app/utils` folder?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon yes .I need to parse that countries.json file placed in this directory app/utils/countries.json .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below codes worked for me to retrieve the local path json objects and shown it to command prompt.

**getdata.component.ts**

```
   import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Http,Response} from '@angular/http';
import { HttpModule }      from '@angular/http';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
   export class GetData {


constructor(private _http:Http) {

}


 getObjectData() {

 return this._http.get('/utils/countries.json')
   .map(data => console.log("Test", JSON.stringify(data.json())));

} 

}
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";

 import { GetData } from './pages/getData.component';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
 import {Http,Response, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';

 @Component({
    selector: "ns-app",
    templateUrl: "app.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./app.css"],
    providers: [GetData]
 })

  export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

     setData : string;
     objectData : any;

     constructor(public getData: GetData, private http: Http) {
   
  }

  ngOnInit() {

   console.log("first", "Test");

   this.getData.getJsonObject()
  .subscribe(data => this.getData = JSON.stringify(data),
   error => alert(error),
   () => console.log("finished")

  );      

  }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

`arrList = require("./utils/countries.json")` should do the trick. `arrList` would then become `{"countries": [...]}`

Comment: you might not need the `./` in the require string

Comment: I dont know how to parse datas.I didn't find any sample related to this.I gone through only http related sample for json.it seems here I dont need that http, as I need to parse it in local path.

Comment: what do you mean? assigning `arrList` to the countries.json file means that `arrList[0].id` is equal to 1, `arrList[1].id` is equal to 2 and so on

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `import { Http } from "@angular/http";`

The NSHttp object from NativeScript will look in the local file system if the url begins with ~/

With this you can replace the url depending if the user is online or offline.

```
getCountries(): Promise<any>  {
        return this.http.get("~/utils/countries.json", this.createRequestOptions())
            .toPromise()
            .then(resp => 
                resp.json()
            )
            .catch((error) => { 
                console.log(error);
            });
}

private createRequestOptions() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    // set headers here e.g.
    //headers.append("AuthKey", "my-key");
    //headers.append("AuthToken", "my-token");
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return options;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can just read synchronously from the file, for instance:

```
import * as fs from 'tns-core-modules/file-system';

const countries = this.getJSONdata("countries.json");

getJSONdata(fileName: string) {
   const folder = this.getFolder("utils");
   const jsonFileName = fs.path.join(folder.path, fileName);
   const jsonFile = fs.File.fromPath(jsonFileName);
   const data = jsonFile.readTextSync().trim();
   if (data.length === 0) { data = "[]"; }

   return JSON.parse(data);
}

getFolder(folderName: string) {
   const path = fs.path.join(fs.knownFolders.currentApp().path, folderName);
   const folder = fs.Folder.fromPath(path);

   return folder;
}
```

Comment: The above "fromPath" calls will create folders/files if needed.